Injecting json data source configuration into Spring Boot App
Our devopses are using Vault Agent sidecar to inject json file with properties into pod. SO I have to read datasource login and pass from there. I can't find exactly how to read those properties. I've found how to provide json explicitly into command line, but not find. Or to use custom property loader, but I do not know how it will work with default one, because I still need to read from application.yml.
How do I read this json file? It structured like this:
{
"spring.datasource.username":"user",
"spring.datasource.password":"password
}

